# Web API 2 helper functions are not available in ASP.NET 5 Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the helper functions from ASP.NET Web API 2 in an ASP.NET 5 Web API. The only one that is still available is OK(). I can't find BadRequest(), Conflict(), etc..

Were these functions replaced? Is there a new way of doing things like this in ASP.NET 5 Web API?

Comment: you mean httpstatuscode?

Comment: I don't think so. I just want an idea of how people are handling responses using asp.net 5 since it seems like a lot has changed since web api is done in a class that inherits from Controller now.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood what you were trying to tell me: http://wildermuth.com/2015/09/27/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_5_-_The_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these results using the *HttpResults* and *ObjectctResults*, see a example how return a bad request(400):

```
[HttpDelete("api/any")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromForm]List<long> ids)
{
     try
     {
         _service.Delete(ids);
          return new HttpOkResult();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error");
     }
}
```

> But for more results with given status code see here all results that vNext has : [vNext Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/eef6c3883a7e27b8387b0925f0b6a88df0a484c5/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core)

Comment: In asp.net 5 all classes whether controller or web api inherit from controller.

Comment: @BlakeRivell my bad, i dont see it is VNext, i will edit my answer

Comment: I noticed in asp.net 5 all web api functions are usually IActionResult and I guess you are supposed to use things like HttpOkResult and BadRequestObjectResult. Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 2):

HttpStatusCodeResult is the class for MVC. You can easily create extension methods for BadRequest() and etc.

Comment: Nice suggest, he can create a extension methos for Controller that return a ````new BadRequestObjectResult()```` or whatever result he want.

Comment: I just found this post which is very useful. So HttpStatusCodeResult is the new way to go: http://wildermuth.com/2015/09/27/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_5_-_The_API